# AVPlayer with AVPlayerLayer not playing video

Tags: ios, iphone, avplayer

I've got a video file named `Intro.m4v` which has a target membership on my app target (and the video itself is straight from iPhone so I'm pretty sure it's iPhone-supported).

I'm trying to play the video as follows (`self.videoContainer` is a fullscreen view inside my view controller, and double checked, it's not `nil`. Also, the player and player layer are strongly referenced instance variables inside my view controller class):

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    player = [AVPlayer playerWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:@"Intro.m4v"]];
    playerLayer = [AVPlayerLayer playerLayerWithPlayer:player];
    playerLayer.frame = self.videoContainer.layer.frame;
    [self.videoContainer.layer addSublayer:playerLayer];

}

-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    [player play];
}

-(void)viewDidLayoutSubviews{
    [super viewDidLayoutSubviews];
    playerLayer.frame = self.videoContainer.layer.frame;
}
```

However, nothing is playing. All I'm seeing is the background color of my video container view (and all the views in front of it, in that manner). What am I doing wrong?

Comment: is your video in app bundle ? and once try to put `didload`'s code in `willAppear` or `didAppear`!

Comment: maybe, the problem is that `AVPlayerLayer `'s size is still zero when you execute `[player play];`? what if you start playback in `viewDidAppear:`?

Comment: @Lion yep, and I was just answering my question when you wrote the comment :) it was related to bundle and URL, see my answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your URL should be like this if your video is in a bundle:

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Intro" ofType:@"m4v"];
NSURL *yourVideoUrl = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];
```

Answer (score 1):

Oops found the problem myself. I was using `[NSURL fileURLWithPath:@"Intro.m4v"]` whereas I had to use `[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"Intro" withExtension:@"m4v"]`.

Fixing the URL resolved the issue.

Comment: I didn't even think of this part :)

Comment: @ArtemStepanenko yup, but your comment is also helpful in many cases as layer/view sizes being zero is a very common issue :)

Answer (score -1):

Try This

```
func playVideo(urlString: String, location : Int) {        
        let videoURL = URL(string: urlString)
        let player = AVPlayer(url: videoURL!)
        let playerViewController = AVPlayerViewController()
        playerViewController.player = player
        self.present(playerViewController, animated: true) {
            playerViewController.player!.play()
        }

    }
```

Comment: I am not using player view controller, I'm trying to display video inside my custom view controller as a backgrond.